# Where is %PUBLICDOCUMENTS%? (shell:Common Documents)?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I need an expansion that gives the current location of public documents.  `%PUBLIC%` expands to C:\Users\Public, but I haven't found any equivalent for public documents.

`%PUBLICDOCUMENTS%`, `%COMMONDOCUMENTS%`, and `%SHAREDDOCUMENTS%` are not recognized by Windows 7.  My public documents folder is not usually at %PUBLIC%\Documents, so I can't use that.

Is there one I can use?  (Is there a complete list somewhere?  Running `set` at the command line doesn't show `%PUBLIC%`, and I know that exists.  Are there others that don't come up with `set`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no environment variable for common documents. I think you have two options:

1. Create a variable yourself and set the value manually
2. You figure it out dynamically when the batch file is running (I would recommend this)

For option **1**, just create a variable and set the value to `C:\Users\Public`.
See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables) for more details about environment variables.

For option **2**, simply read the value from the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Common Documents` to a variable and then use it.

Here's the command for doing this  (Source: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php)

```
FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /V "Common Documents" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET CommonDocs=%%B
```

Output:

[image]